# Why wont my React App run in Safari 10.1?

Tags: webpack, safari, fetch, polyfills

My app works fine in other browsers, but it does not load in Safari 10.1 and I'm not sure how to fix it. I thought it could be because Safari 10.1 does not support `fetch`, but I have added a fetch polyfill (`whatwg-fetch`) to my webpack.config.js and it still does not work:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    back: ["@babel/polyfill", "whatwg-fetch", "./back-end/index.jsx"],
    ...
  },
  output: {
    ...
```

Here is a screenshot of the error console:
[image: error console]

Here is a screenshot of the network tab:
[image: network tab]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem and it was `fetch` related.

I read [this thread](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/610#issuecomment-418549020) that states:

> It's a problem with fetch - I guess with Safari you are required to pass in `credentials: 'include'`, otherwise it doesn't send cookies (unlike in Chrome).

I noticed that in my screenshot of the network tab, the API call to `/user` was returning a 401, which means the user is *not* logged in... but that API call happens after the user *is* logged in, which does sound like a cookie problem.

To fix it I just had to add `credentials: 'include'` to my generic `get()` function, that uses `fetch`:

```
export const get = async function(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: "include"    // added this for safari 10
  });
  return await response.json();
};
```

Comment: This seems to be the case for Safari 14 as well.